# What does this double negative mean?

Tags: grammar

**Nothing in the court papers suggests Grayson was anything but a victim of the scheme.**

Does this mean papers suggest he was a victim?

Comment: To say that the "papers suggest he was a victim" might be putting it too strongly; but at least the papers *do not suggest he was a perpetrator*, for example.

Comment: What double negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's arguably awkward phrasing, but yes, it means that the papers suggest (by omission, perhaps) that he was a victim. Or rather, he could not be anything other than a victim based on what is in (or omitted from) the papers.

Answer (score 2):

The format of the double-negative, here, is a *reinforcement* of Grayson's status as a victim in the eyes of the court.

Comment: The way you explained it, it makes it so obvious now. :)

Comment: After waking up a bit, I now realize that my previous comment was ambiguous and could be misinterpreted. What I had meant was that I like your post (and I had +1 it), and it was that word "*reinforcement*" that made everything so clear to me. :) -- So often, one can get too involved in the things happening under the covers, such as how to syntactically parse an expression, that the big picture meaning of a sentence gets lost.

Comment: Actually, it was quite clear.  no worries.

Answer (score 1):

No, it means pretty much what it says: There is nothing to be found in them to suggest he *wasn't* a victim.

The statement says nothing whatsoever about anything the papers may hold to suggest that he *was* a victim. There could be something to that effect in there, or there could not. We aren't given any information on that in the statement you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, try removing the difficult phrases one at a time.

> The court papers suggest Grayson was anything but a victim of the
>   scheme.

Here the use of *anything but* stresses that Grayson is highly unlikely to be a victim of the scheme.

> Nothing in the court papers suggests Grayson was a victim of the
>   scheme.

Here there is no evidence in the papers that suggests Grayson was a victim.

Both of the above examples, using only one negative,  indicate that Grayson is not a victim.

Therefore, using both phrases together in a double negative means that Grayson IS likely to be a victim.